# setlocale in Mac OS X 10.7 lion

Tags: c, macos

I am writing a program in C, which sorts words in a file appropriately to a chosen localization and encoding. I am using MAC OS X 10.7. The problem is, the call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL)` always returns `C`, even if I call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` before that to set `LC_CTYPE` to the default environment settings. Can somebody explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it simply means the default locale is `"C"`. What did you expect?

Using `setlocale` with a `NULL` pointer will return the program's current locale (not changing it).

Using `setlocale` with `""` will select the user's locale, based on the software's environment variables.

So in your case, it's `"C"` in both case. Seems like normal behavior.